# Issues with C++ and Qt/QML data exchange

Tags: c++, json, qt, qml

Why do I get this error in the QML code: `ReferenceError: m_jsonDocStr is not defined`,
even if `m_jsonDocStr` is specified here in the C++ code:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString m_jsonDocStr READ jsonDocToStr WRITE setJsonDocStr NOTIFY jsonDocStrChanged)
```

And why the QmlLink.open() C++ function is not opened from QML? (neither as a normal member function nor as a slot)

```
TypeError: Property 'open' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Next, with the "<--" comment I point to the critical lines of the code, with the error messages I get.

This is the QML file:

```
/** Main.qml */

import QtCore
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtQuick.Layouts
import main

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Data input widget")
    
    property string dataFilename: ""
    property string dataFile: ""
    
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            Action {
                text: qsTr("&Open...")
                onTriggered: fileDialog.open()
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollView {
        id: fileContents
        anchors.fill: parent
        property string dataFile: m_jsonDocStr  // <-- ReferenceError: m_jsonDocStr is not defined
        TextArea {
            text: "File: " + dataFilename + "\n" + dataFile + "\nLength: " + dataFile.length
        }
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Open data file"
        nameFilters: ["JSON files (*.json)"]
        onAccepted: {
            dataFilename = selectedFile
            console.log("Open file: " + dataFilename)
            QmlLink.open(dataFilename)      // <-- TypeError: Property 'open' of object [object Object] is not a function
            console.log("File contents: " + m_jsonDocStr)
        }
        onRejected: {
            console.log("No file selected.")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the header file:

```
/** QmlLink.hpp */

#ifndef QMLLINK_HPP
#define QMLLINK_HPP

#include <QObject>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QtQml/qqmlregistration.h>

class QmlLink : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QJsonDocument m_jsonDoc READ jsonDoc WRITE setJsonDoc NOTIFY jsonDocChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString m_jsonDocStr READ jsonDocToStr WRITE setJsonDocStr NOTIFY jsonDocStrChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
    explicit QmlLink(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    QJsonDocument jsonDoc() const { return m_jsonDoc; }
    void          setJsonDoc(const QJsonDocument &jsonDoc) { m_jsonDoc = jsonDoc; }
    QString       jsonDocToStr() const { return m_jsonDoc.toJson(); }
    void          setJsonDocStr(const QString &jsonDoc) { m_jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonDoc.toUtf8()); }

signals:
    void jsonDocChanged();
    void jsonDocStrChanged();

public slots:
    void menuOpen();
    int  open(QString filePath);

private:
    QJsonDocument m_jsonDoc;
    QString m_jsonDocStr;

    QString m_jsonFileName = "default.json";
};

#endif // QMLLINK_HPP
```

This is the implementation file:

```
/** QmlLink.cpp */

#include "QmlLink.hpp"
#include <iostream> 
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQuickView>

QmlLink::QmlLink(QObject *parent) : QObject{parent} {}

void QmlLink::menuOpen() {
    open(m_jsonFileName);
}

int QmlLink::open(QString filePath)
{
    m_jsonFileName = filePath;

    QUrl url(filePath);
    QFile jsonFile;
    jsonFile.setFileName(url.toLocalFile());

    if(jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) == false) {
        return -1;
    }

    const QByteArray data = jsonFile.readAll();
    m_jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);

    const QString strDoc(m_jsonDoc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));

    std::cout << "Data file contents: " << strDoc.toStdString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is a classic main() function:

```
/** main.cpp */

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "QmlLink.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QmlLink qmlLink;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/main/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    QQmlContext *rootContext = engine.rootContext();
    rootContext->setContextProperty("QmlLink", &qmlLink);

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is the trivial JSON file:

```
{
    "Array": [
        true,
        999,
        "string"
    ],
    "Key": "Value",
    "null": null
}
```

Tools versions:

- Qt 6.5
- OS: Linux
- gcc 13.1
- clang 15

Comment: I know there is [this repo](https://github.com/kromain/qml-utils) which implements JSONListModel in QML. Maybe this help you.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the context property before loading the url :

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QmlLink qmlLink;

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
// set the context property here
QQmlContext *rootContext = engine.rootContext();
rootContext->setContextProperty("QmlLink", &qmlLink);

const QUrl url(u"qrc:/main/Main.qml"_qs);
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
    &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
    Qt::QueuedConnection);
engine.load(url);
```

and fix the `Main.qml` :

```
/** Main.qml */

import QtCore
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Data input widget")
    
    property string dataFilename: ""
    
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            Action {
                text: qsTr("&Open...")
                onTriggered: fileDialog.open()
            }
        }
    }

    ScrollView {
        id: fileContents
        anchors.fill: parent
        property string dataFile: QmlLink.m_jsonDocStr // add context property
        TextArea {
            // add id of the ScrollView to access dataFile
            text: "File: " + dataFilename + "\n" + fileContents.dataFile + "\nLength: " + fileContents.dataFile.length
        } 
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: "Open data file"
        nameFilters: ["JSON files (*.json)"]
        onAccepted: {
            dataFilename = selectedFile
            console.log("Open file: " + dataFilename)
            QmlLink.open(dataFilename)
            // add context property 
            console.log("File contents: " + QmlLink.m_jsonDocStr)
        }
        onRejected: {
            console.log("No file selected.")
        }
    }
}
```

To display the content of the file in the `ScrollView`, there is also a little change needed in `QmlLink.cpp` :

```
int QmlLink::open(QString filePath)
{
    m_jsonFileName = filePath;

    QUrl url(filePath);
    QFile jsonFile;
    jsonFile.setFileName(url.toLocalFile());

    if(jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) == false) {
        return -1;
    }

    const QByteArray data = jsonFile.readAll();
    m_jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);

    const QString strDoc(m_jsonDoc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));

    std::cout << "Data file contents: " << strDoc.toStdString() << std::endl;

    emit jsonDocStrChanged(); // update the property for QML

    return 0;
}
```

and in `QmlLink.hpp` :

```
void setJsonDocStr(const QString &jsonDoc) 
{ 
  m_jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonDoc.toUtf8());
  emit jsonDocStrChanged(); // update the property for QML
}
```

Comment: I set the context property before loading the URL, but I still get the same error. I fixed the `Main.qml` file as you wrote, and now I get: "Unable to assign [undefined] to QString".

Comment: I have reproduced your errors with Qt 6.2.4 on Debian 11 and could fix it with the code above.  Do you have some compiler warnings ?

Comment: I have also updated the answer to fix the display in the console and in the `ScrollView`.

Comment: I applied your changes, thank you for that. However, I still get error `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString` on line with comment "// add context property" in `ScrollView`. And `TypeError: Property 'open' of object [object Object] is not a function` when calling `QmlLink.open()`. The JSON path is: `file:///home/pietrom/qmlgui/default.json`

Comment: I doubt it is related to the Qt version (6.2 vs 6.5) but just in case, i can see some changes in [QtDoc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperties) , especially the added Note. However, i don't have a 6.5 version at hand to investigate further.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't pass `QJsonDocument` from C++ to QML.
As you mentioned you will get an "Unable to assign [undefined] to QString" error.
But My Idea is to pass QByteArray.

Here is my example:

In main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QDebug>

class FileLoader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FileLoader(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

public slots:
    void openFile()
    {
        QString filePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(nullptr, "Open JSON File", "", "JSON Files (*.json)");

        if (!filePath.isEmpty()) {
            QFile file(filePath);
            if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
                QByteArray data = file.readAll();
                file.close();

                QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data);
                qDebug() << "JSON File Loaded:" << filePath;
                emit fileLoaded(jsonDoc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented));
            }
        }
    }

signals:
    void fileLoaded(const QByteArray &jsonData);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Create an instance of the FileLoader
    FileLoader fileLoader;

    // Register the FileLoader as a context property
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("fileLoader", &fileLoader);

    // Load the QML file
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/QmlJson/Main.qml"));
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

in Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 300
    title: "JSON Viewer"

    Text {
        id: jsonDataText
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Button {
        text: "Open JSON"
        onClicked: fileLoader.openFile()
    }

    Connections {
        target: fileLoader
        function onFileLoaded(jsonData) {
            jsonDataText.text = jsonData
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my result:**

[image]